# I have a lambda with a role that has full access to SQS but I still can't send messages to SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, roles, policies

Please help, I've been defeated by AWS...

I have a lambda with the following permissions.

[image]

Neither sqs resource-based policy nor the service role has any `Deny` statements. The lambda should send a message to another SQS queue but it can't, instead I just get this error

```
{
    "code": "AccessDenied",
    "time": "2021-06-03T20:50:09.722Z",
    "requestId": "62e15127-9f9b-527f-b1a8-0814dd5a5c9a",
    "statusCode": 403,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 47.17774745450638,
    "level": "error",
    "message": "Access to the resource https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ is denied.",
    "timestamp": "2021-06-03T20:50:09.723Z"
}
```

The lambda code that should do this (this code is normally on multiple files)

```
import { SQSEvent } from 'aws-lambda';
import { isLeft } from 'fp-ts/lib/Either';
import { first } from 'lodash';
import reporter from 'io-ts-reporters';
import ExitWithSuccess from 'Entities/ExitWithSuccess';
import { error } from '@mvf/logger';
import { SQS } from 'aws-sdk';
import Event from './Event';

const sqsClient = new SQS({
  region: 'eu-west-1',
});

const delayed = {
  client: sqsClient,
  url: 'https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<account>/event_dispatcher_delayed_messages',
};

type ISqsClient = typeof delayed;
interface SqsOperations {
  sendMessage(body: Record<string, unknown>): Promise<unknown>;
}

const sqs = {
  instance: ({ client, url }: ISqsClient): SqsOperations => ({
    sendMessage: (body: Record<string, unknown>) =>
      client
        .sendMessage({ QueueUrl: url, MessageBody: JSON.stringify(body) })
        .promise(),
  }),
  delayed,
};

const lambda = async (event: SQSEvent): Promise<void> => {
  const record = first(event.Records);
  if (!record) {
    throw new ExitWithSuccess(error, 'lambda was invoked without any records');
  }

  const maybeEvent = Event.decode(JSON.parse(record.body));
  if (isLeft(maybeEvent)) {
    throw new ExitWithSuccess(error, 'invalid record body', {
      typeErrors: reporter.report(maybeEvent),
    });
  }

  await sqs.instance(delayed).sendMessage(maybeEvent.right);
};

export default lambda;
```

I've now spent 3 days on this, has anyone encountered a similar issue?
How is it possible to have full access to resources and still not be able to interact with it?

Any tips, suggestions or ideas as to what is going on here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the code that is running?

Comment: @JasonWadsworth I've updated my question with the lambda code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the SQS queue have its resource-based policy that explicitly denies access?

Is the SQS queue in the same account where the Lambda function is? otherwise, you need to allow cross-account access too.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-basic-examples-of-sqs-policies.html

Comment: The queue does have a policy but there are no `Deny` statements in it, only allow statements

Comment: is the SQS queue in the same account where the Lambda function is deployed?

Comment: Actually, account was the issue... this stack was original deployed to a different account, I've redeployed it to a new account and didn't consider the fact that queue URLs are hard coded so instead of sending messages to queues in current account I was trying to send messages to the queues in the previous account, which obviously my lambda did not have rights to do. I knew it was something silly :D